# Creating two WiFi Access Points with a single Raspberry Pi (3B) with usb adaptor

Tags: wifi, access-point, systemd-networkd

I am Raspberry Pi (3B) and the Pi converted wireless access point using [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way/88234#88234) and wlan0 works well. I repeated the process for wlan1 (USB adapter) as suggested by [How to create two WiFi Access Points with a single Raspberry Pi with usb adaptor](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100506/how-to-create-two-wifi-access-points-with-a-single-raspberry-pi-with-usb-adaptor). When reboot wlan1 works but wlan0 stops working. The error message is very strange. When I am only using wlan0, it works perfectly but I got following results when both wlan0 and wlan1 connected.
Status of both wlan1 and wlan0 are as follows

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
● wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-30 14:30:30 AEST; 27min ago
 Main PID: 305 (wpa_supplicant)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-wpa_supplicant.slice/wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
           └─305 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan1

May 30 14:30:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
May 30 14:30:30 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 30 14:30:32 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=AU
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: Failed to create interface mon.wlan1: -95 (Operation not supported)
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: wlan1: Could not connect to kernel driver
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: Using interface wlan1 with hwaddr b8:27:eb:7e:78:7a and ssid "RPi1"
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: wlan1: AP-ENABLED
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[305]: wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to b8:27:eb:7e:78:7a completed [id=0 id_str=]



pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
● wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-30 15:40:12 AEST; 26s ago
 Main PID: 2586 (wpa_supplicant)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-wpa_supplicant.slice/wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
           └─2586 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0

May 30 15:40:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
May 30 15:40:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 30 15:40:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
May 30 15:40:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May 30 15:40:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: rfkill: Cannot get wiphy information
May 30 15:40:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
May 30 15:40:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
May 30 15:40:13 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: wlan0: Driver does not support AP mode
May 30 15:40:13 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[2586]: wlan0: Driver does not support AP mode
```

The status of systemd-networkd.service

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-05-30 14:30:28 AEST; 29min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 142 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─142 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

May 30 14:30:28 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: Enumeration completed
May 30 14:30:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
May 30 14:30:29 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: eth0: IPv6 enabled for interface: Success
May 30 14:30:29 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: wlan0: IPv6 enabled for interface: Success
May 30 14:30:31 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: eth0: Gained carrier
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: wlan1: Gained carrier
May 30 14:30:33 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
May 30 14:30:34 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: wlan1: Gained IPv6LL
May 30 14:30:36 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 10.0.0.23/24 via 10.0.0.138
May 30 14:30:47 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[142]: wlan1: Configured
```

When I added wlan1, wlan0 stops working, why? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: *The error message is very strange* - which error message do you find "strange" - why is it "strange"?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. If you look on the status of the status of wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service, it says wlan0: Driver does not support AP mode but it was running well when I ran only wlan0.  Therefore, I find it is strange. you will more details on status output. Thank you.

Comment: looks like wlan1 is the onboard wifi from the MAC address `b8:27:eb:7e:78:7a` - perhaps the USB device on wlan0 doesn't support AP mode - what is your USB wifi device?

Comment: Yes you are right MAC address is belongs to onboard wifi but it shows SSID of wlan1 not wlan0 and therefore, I am confused. I am using TP-LINK WN725N as USB wifi device and the following link says it is working with RPi.          https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters

Comment: obviously when you plug in a USB wifi dongle, the onboard is becoming wlan1 ... you say you have a WN725N - but the table doesn't show one of those at all, so it may well not support AP mode ... can you share the vendorID/productID of that adapter (use lsusb) - oh, wait, there's notes about it later ... is it a v1 or v2?

Comment: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter. I think it is v2.

Comment: yeah, so you've gone through the install of the drivers for that? as per the link you gave earlier? i.e. *Raspbian requires manual driver installation and manual update after each kernel upgrade. **Limited range*** - I'd get a different USB wifi to be honest - seems like too much work and with limited range, why would you bother

Comment: Nope, I have not done any new installation. If you have link, please give me. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't say a "new installation" ... I said that page you linked to requires ***manual driver installation*** - the link is in the page YOU linked to so - find your device in [the link you provided](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) and follow the link to the instructions they recommend